# Why should we install Laravel with composer?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I downloaded **Laravel** from github and save it on **c:/htdocs/laravel1**
and I created a copy of my laravel with **CMD (with composer)** and I install this as **laravel2** in **c:/htdocs/laravel2** directory.

Laravel1:

> c:/htdocs/laravel1

---

Laravel2:

> c:/htdocs/laravel2

And I have access to both of them in **localhost:8080/laravel1/public/** and 
 **localhost:8080/laravel2/public/**

My question is : ***Why should I install laravel by composer? There is no different between the installed laravel and downloaded laravel.***

Answer (score 6):

There are many, many valid reasons to use composer:

- Composer creates optimized autoloaders if you want it to
- Allows you to add thrird party dependencies easily (just add them to composer.json)
- You can track the composer.lock file, and use composer install to ensure the exact same versions of the dependencies are being used throughout (on all environments, by everyone contribbuting) *This is a must-have, if you're using automated builds!*
- Updating all dependencies, including Laravel, is a simple matter of `composer update`
- Composer supports post-install and post-update scripts, to be executed after a composer install/update is run. This is quite commonly used to prompt the dev for configuration parameters. Downloading the code means you have to edit the config files by hand, and worse of all: track them in git or svn
- ... I'll probably add more reasons along the way, these are just a few off the top of my head

**Update**:

Just thought of some more reasons why using composer is a good idea:

- Composer packages themselves can, and often do, define dependencies and requirements. Things like `"php": ">=5.4.0",` or `"ext-curl": "*"` will alert you to any missing PHP extensions or a version mismatch. These requirements can also trigger composer to fetch additional dependencies. Which brings me on to the next point:
- ***Laravel itself has dependencies:*** Laravel uses components from Symfony2, for example. The easiest way to manage its own dependencies is to use composer, seeing as Symfony does, too. If you run `composer update`, the dependencies of Laravel will be checked, and updated where needed. Doing this manually is possible, but it's tedious, and really not worth the bother. Repetitive, dull jobs make people grumpy. Computers don't have this problem.

Comment: Good list of reasons for using composer

Answer (score 1):

Composer is a dependancy manager similar to node's npm which allows quick and easy management of 3rd party libraries & packages on a per-project basis.

I recommend reading https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md to find out more about composer and explore https://packagist.org to find out the kind of things that are available through composer

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, does it? The OP wants to know why, if you're starting a new Laravel project, you'd have to use composer instead of simply downloading the source and dumping it into the desired destination

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I am answering why you would want to use composer by encouraging the OP to read up on what it is so that he can understand it

Comment: The way I read the OP's question is that he's not sure why, if all you're going to use is Laravel, you really need composer. That's not the same thing as installing npm packages when you're working on a node project. The OP wants to start a laravel project (think of it as installing node), and is asking why he'd need to use composer (install npm), if he's not planning to use third party packages

Comment: Fair enough, +1 for your answer :)